# How to compare two tables and show every difference?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 table with diferent data

```
 Finance                    Orderan
+-----------------+        +---------------+ 
| id |  no_order  |        | id| no_order  |
+-----------------+        +---------------+ 
| 1  | 1234567890 |        | 1 | 1234567890|
| 2  | 0987654321 |        | 2 | 0987654321|          |
| 3  | 1122334455 |        | 3 | 1122334455|
| 4  | 1212121212 |        | 4 | 2222222222|
+-----------------+        +---------------+
```

I want to return diferent data like this:

```
+-------------------------+     
| no_order   |  no_order  |       
+-------------------------+        
| 1212121212 | 2222222222 |                
+-------------------------+
```

Comment: you can use a join statement

Comment: Do you want to get the rows that have the same `id` but different `no_order`? What if Finance table has `3  | 1122334455` and Orderan has `5  | 1122334455`, do you consider them same or different?

Comment: You can use `INNER JOIN` in Mysql or MSSql to get values which does not match in both tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need in simple

```
SELECT t1.no_order, t2.no_order
FROM Finance t1
JOIN Orderan t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
WHERE t1.no_order != t2.no_order
```

?